# How to change global type declaration to already declared type via NPM package?

Tags: typescript, ethereum

I have installed @walletconnect/web3-provider": "^1.6.6".
In **node_modules/walletlink/dist/index.d.ts** this package describes the global **window.ethereum** type:

```js
import { WalletLinkProvider } from "./provider/WalletLinkProvider";
import { WalletLink } from "./WalletLink";
export { WalletLinkProvider } from "./provider/WalletLinkProvider";
export { WalletLink } from "./WalletLink";
export default WalletLink;

declare global {
    interface Window {
        WalletLink: typeof WalletLink;
        WalletLinkProvider: typeof WalletLinkProvider;
        ethereum?: WalletLinkProvider;
        walletLinkExtension?: WalletLinkProvider;
    }
}
```

I need to add the autoRefreshOnNetworkChange field:

```js
window.ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;
```

The question is: **How to change window.ethereum type?**
Should / Can I extend the WalletLinkProvider to do it?

It doesn't work:

```js
declare module 'walletlink' {
    export class WalletLinkProvider {
        autoRefreshOnNetworkChange: boolean
    }
}
```

It doesn't work too:

```js
declare module 'walletlink/dist/provider/WalletLinkProvider' {
    export class WalletLinkProvider {
        autoRefreshOnNetworkChange: boolean
    }
}
```

I always get error:

> TS2339: Property 'autoRefreshOnNetworkChange' does not exist on type
> 'WalletLinkProvider'.

When I try to change somehow globally:

```js
declare global {
    interface Window {
        ethereum?: any
    }
}
```

I get:

> TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.
> Property 'ethereum' must be of type 'WalletLinkProvider', but here has
> type 'any'.  index.d.ts(10, 9): 'ethereum' was also declared here.